# UIButton click not working if subview of UIWIndow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am creating an iOS library. My library when initiated from AppDelegate will create a button on top of the screen.

I have created the button and it is showing up. But when I click, the target method is not evoked.

This is how I have created the button and assigned its action in the library

```
- (void) addLoginButton {
UIWindow *appWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
UIButton *loginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[loginButton setFrame:CGRectMake((appWindow.frame.size.width/2)-35, 20, 70, 20)];
[loginButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[loginButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[loginButton setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(auLoginClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[appWindow addSubview:loginButton];
if([appWindow.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    UINavigationController *navCon = (UINavigationController *)(appWindow.rootViewController);
    if (!navCon.navigationBar.isHidden) {
        navCon.navigationBar.layer.zPosition = 0;
    }
}
loginButton.layer.zPosition = 5;
}

- (void) auLoginClicked {
NSLog(@"Hello");
}
```

Comment: i think you have to take Uiview then add in upper layer of window. uiview should be added with button. try this

Comment: dont use the layer `loginButton.layer.zPosition = 5;`

Comment: use bringSubViewFront, if it is not.

Comment: [window setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; I think this can work. And always add on upper layer uibutton

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: @RichardG ... I have already tried that.. It does not work.

Comment: @HensonFang .. I am developing a library.. The developer using my library may or may not use a stroyboard

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik -- Can you please suggest another way to keep my button always on top?

Comment: where you called this `addLoginButton`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik... I called this inside my library init method

Comment: call direct in appdelegate, surely works, now the delegete not fired properly UIWindow *appWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];

Comment: @ajjjjjjjj.... I used [window setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; and still its not working. I cant add by taking uiview. I need the button in all views

Comment: did you find a solution? same problem here

Comment: I had same issue and removing animations made it work but I need animations so going to figure out. Please answer if anyone figured out. Thanks

Comment: I had same issue and removing animations made it work but I need animations so going to figure out. Please answer if anyone figured out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIWindow *appWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[appWindow addSubview:view];
```

You just need to fetch the `keyWindow` of the application and add the button as a subview. You **don't** have to set the `zPosition`

Answer (score 2):

I copied your code and have the same result.It's really strange and i am still working on it.I confirm it is the storyboard that caused the result,because i use your code in my project which does not use the storyboard,it works properly.

But please do not use `loginButton.layer.zPosition = 5;`It is not a proper way .

Here are some advices:

But If are you using UINavigationController Use:

```
[self.navigationController.view.window addSubview:aView];
```

If are you using UITabBarController Use:

```
[self.tabBarController.view.window addSubview:aView];
```

In AppDelegate you can directly assign a view to window. In appDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method Use:

```
[self.window addSubview:aView];
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I am developing a library and in the AppDelegate the only call will be to initiate the library. The developer using my library will initialize it from AppDelegate and I have to add the button whatever type of controller it is.

Comment: maybe you can give an API for your users,something like this  showButtonInView:(UIView)view and let your users to choose which container to show the button

Comment: I need the button on top on all the view controllers.

Comment: Did you get this solution @AravindGS

Comment: @Abhishek .. Yes. I will add it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding your button as a subview of window add this
then your button will get action.
[appWindow.rootViewController.view addSubview:loginButton];

If you add your view(Button) as a subview of window, then it won't be able to get events from user.That is the reason why your button not responding to event.
Debug it you will come to understand:)

If you want that to be on the top of every viewController, then check if UINavigationController is not the initialViewController then create a your own NavigationController and make it as initialContoller. It will make your button will be visible throughout the app(until the user by himself present any other VC)

Comment: This kind of works.. But I need the button to be there in all views. If I add a Modal view controller then the button will not be visible anymore.

Comment: You can do one thing set a tag for that button and bring that button to front using [window bringSubviewToFront:[window viewWithTag:1523]];

Comment: Still wont work.. Consider the rootview controller is a UINavigationController. When you add the button as a subview to the navigation controller, all the views controllers being pushed (show) on that navigation controller will get the button. Bu when you present a modal controller the button will go below

Comment: Yes, If you consider UINavigationController as root then add the following code topVC of NavigationController .   UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:[window viewWithTag:1523]];

Comment: I am building a library.. The rootview controller can be anything according to the need of the developer using my library. I need to have a generalised solution. The rootview controller can be a tab bar controller, split view controller, pages controller anything